# Can I create an index FROM another index?

Tags: sphinx

I am doing various regepx_filters in an index to modify the stored index text, this from data that is originally in tagged html format (multiple zones). After I do so is is possible to now make a second index based on the first modified index that uses only one of the zones in the original index?

```
index_zones = Title, Author, Description
```

Can I, after indexing this with a custom configuration, then duplicate this index in some way that says

`Create IndexB based on IndexA using ZONE:(Title) only`

Say for instance I did the following regexp:

```
regexp_filter=(<Title>.*?ipad.*?)(<\/Title>)<Description>.*?Used.*?<\/Description>=>\1 Used\2 in order to index used into the Title Zone.
```

Now I want to reindex or make a new index with just the newly indexed

```
<Title>Bla bla ipad bla bla Used</Title>
```

is this possible?  If not can I then update my Mysql table with the newly indexed text?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to create an index based on an existing sphinx index. I also don't think its possible to retrieve the regexp_filtered result - im pretty sure its only available to query against.

Why dont you do your regex's before sphinx indexing? For example, create a new db column `ipad_used_regex` and populate this with whatever scripting language you choose. Or using `mariaDb` with the [PCRE Regex Enhancements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26179601/4852737) you could build the regex match into the SQL, something like this:

```
SELECT Title, REGEXP_REPLACE(Title, "(<Title>.*?ipad.*?)(<\/Title>)<Description>.*?Used.*?<\/Description>", '\\1 Used\\2') as ipad_used_regex
FROM `your_table`
```

You could then use this SQL in your sphinx index source?

Comment: I think using the SQl in the source might get cumbersome as my example was a quite simple and watered down one of the actual but yeah it seems as if in this case I am going to have to pre-process the mysql which will add  an unavoidable overhead which is too bad. zone_weights would be *quite* a helpful addition!